# Из textbox->text в char* C++

Tags: winforms, c++, visual-studio-2010

Приветствую!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как преобразовать непонятный формат Text'a из textbox'a в MSVS2010 в стандартный массив char'ов. 
Язык С++
Проект Windows Forms

Спасибо!

Comment: Ругается на Marshal. Надо что-то подключать?
И, допустим, если я решил последовать вашему совету насчет использования String^, то как мне передать банально значение из textBox в fopen()?

Answer (score 3):

*(Попробую попасть пальцем в небо, поскольку, судя по всему, вы девелопите с помощью `C++/CLI`, но я могу ошибаться)*

- У `TextBox` есть `property Text`:

  ```
  virtual property String^ Text
  {
      String^ get () override;
      void set (String^ value) override;
  }
  ```
- То есть, обратившись к `textBox->Text`, вы получаете переменную типа `String^`.
- Корректное преобразование из `String^` в массив `char` - не самая тривиальная операция, поскольку `String^` - абстракция намного шире, нежели `char[]`. *Правильно это преобразование операция выполняется так:*

  ```
  IntPtr initialStringPtr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(initialString);
  char* converted = static_cast<char*>(initialStringPtr.ToPointer());

  // Работаете с 'converted'.

  Marshal::FreeHGlobal(initialStringPtr);
  // После этой строчки указатель 'converted' указывает на освобожденный участок памяти!
  ```
- **Рекомендую 300 раз подумать *(а потом подумать еще 300 раз)*, перед тем как переходить от удобной юникодной реализации строки к `char*`.**

Comment: Присоединяюсь.

    "Рекомендую 300 раз подумать (а потом подумать еще 300 раз), перед тем как переходить от удобной юникодной реализации строки к char*."